# How to disable 404 errors and make every directory look like one even if it's not there?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For a project, I need to make every directory (server.com/dir1, server.com/dir2) look like there is the directory, even when there is not. I could say I need a directory wildcard. Say the content would be somewhere on the server, and gets included in the directories. Is there a way to achieve this with .htaccess?
Thanks!

Comment: it is called routing

Comment: Sure that is possible. Actually the old mapping of a URL to a folder in the server side file system is completely outdated and not used any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)/*$ ./yourActualScript.php?directory=$1
```

The regex part in brackets is your folder, the slash star is the rest of the url (if any), and the request will be sent to an actual script with GET var `directory`